# Windows LyX won't open a file created in Mac LyX

Tags: lyx

I created a lyX file yesterday on a Mac.  It won't open in Lyx 2.0.7 on Windows.  I get:

Lyx_tempdir.HP7972/Buffer_convertLyXFormat.cr7972 is not a readable LyX document.

I am pretty certain my file is not corrupted. I don't know the MAC version but it's up to date as I only installed it this week.

My windows installation has Latex installed with Tex Live as i was advised that had better compatibility with Mac OS.

Comment: The error happens before LaTeX is used, so your LaTeX installation details are not necessary (although thanks for giving them!). This sounds like it could be a `lyx2lyx` error. On your Mac, you probably have 2.1.1 (if you only have 2.1, please upgrade as an important bug was just fixed) and LyX needs to convert files saved in 2.0.x to the new format. Something might have gone wrong with the conversion, and you didn't get an error directly from `lyx2lyx` because it did not realize something when wrong. Please post a minimal example that works with 2.0.x and fails with 2.1 so we can fix this bug

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have 2.1.1 on my Mac.  I can transfer a file from Windows LyX (2.0.7) to my Mac ok, but not the other way round.   Is LyX 2.0.7 unable to read a file created in 2.1.1?  If so how do I convert? I can't see anything in the "save as" menu.

Comment: OK, I have verified that a file containing only a few words of standard text in Mac LyX will not open in my Windows LyX.  If it would be helpful for me to upload the file, please give me instructions how to upload it.  Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you update LyX on your Windows to 2.0.8.1, if you prefer not to update to 2.1.1 for some reason. However, if you cannot update on Windows, you can export in LyX 2.1.1 by doing File > Export and choosing `LyX 2.0.x`. Also, note that the beamer interface is very different between 2.1.x and 2.0.x so it is not recommend to continually convert between the two.

Comment: @scottkosty I thought I had installed the latest version.  I must have gone to the wrong download site. I have now updated my windows LyX and the files are compatible in both direction.  Thanks

Comment: glad to hear that things are working well now.

Comment: I had the same problem trying to open LyX files I created on Ubuntu.   The problem was solved after I upgraded my LyX installation on Windows to 2.1.2. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by mismatched versions of LyX.